# How to restore .bak file from azure storage account to SQL Server 2012

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I have a .bak file in azure storage account, and I want to restore that .bak file directly on a SQL Server 2012. What are the solution to restore .bak file from azure storage account to SQL SERVER 2012 directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the CREDENTIAL either with account key or SAS token by using below command:

**Using the URL and the access key**

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [Credential_BLOB]
WITH IDENTITY= 'storage account url',
SECRET = 'storage account key';
```

**Using the Shared Access Signature (SAS)**

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [Credential_Name_SAS]
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'SASToken';
```

Now, you can restore  the backup from the bak file stored in Azure Blob Storage using below  command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Database_Name FROM URL = 'https://StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName/SampleDatabase.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'Credential_BLOB'
```